# Построение графика функции на основе квадратичной интерполяции. Delphi

Tags: delphi, интерполяция

Есть процедура, которая на основании 17 точек (x от -3 до 1 с шагом 0.25) рассчитывает промежуточное значение функции методом квадратичной интерполяции. Для расчета коэффициентов я пользуюсь методом Крамера. На основании полученных результатов нужно построить график. Но в результате график получается абсолютно не соответствующим ожиданиям. Другая процедура, выводящая значение функции на основе аргумента введенного пользователем работает нормально и результаты коррелируют с теми, которые получены методом линейной интерполяции. Таким образом, полагаю, что проблема в графике. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку.

Код функции:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
mat,mata,matb,matc:array[0..2,0..2] of double;
i,k:integer;
xnow,ynow,a,b,deter,detera,deterb,deterc,anow,bnow,cnow,j:double;
begin


  for i := 1 to 15 do
    begin

      for k := 0 to 2 do
      begin
        mat[k,0]:=xar[i+k-1]*xar[i+k-1];
        mat[k,1]:=xar[i+k-1];
        mat[k,2]:=1;
      end;

      deter:=(mat[0,0]*mat[1,1]*mat[2,2])+(mat[0,1]*mat[1,2]*mat[2,0])+(mat[1,0]*mat[2,1]*mat[0,2])
    -(mat[2,0]*mat[1,1]*mat[0,2])-(mat[0,0]*mat[1,2]*mat[2,1])-(mat[1,0]*mat[0,1]*mat[2,2]);

      for k := 0 to 2 do
      begin
        mata[k,0]:=yar[i+k-1];
        mata[k,1]:=xar[i+k-1];
        mata[k,2]:=1;
      end;

      detera:=(mata[0,0]*mata[1,1]*mata[2,2])+(mata[0,1]*mata[1,2]*mata[2,0])+(mata[1,0]*mata[2,1]*mata[0,2])
    -(mata[2,0]*mata[1,1]*mata[0,2])-(mata[0,0]*mata[1,2]*mata[2,1])-(mata[1,0]*mata[0,1]*mata[2,2]);

      for k := 0 to 2 do
        begin
          matb[k,0]:=xar[i+k-1]*xar[i+k-1];
          matb[k,1]:=yar[i+k-1];
          matb[k,2]:=1;
        end;

        deterb:=(matb[0,0]*matb[1,1]*matb[2,2])+(matb[0,1]*matb[1,2]*matb[2,0])+(matb[1,0]*matb[2,1]*matb[0,2])
    -(matb[2,0]*matb[1,1]*matb[0,2])-(matb[0,0]*matb[1,2]*matb[2,1])-(matb[1,0]*matb[0,1]*matb[2,2]);;

      for k := 0 to 2 do
        begin
          matc[k,0]:=xar[i+k-1]*xar[i+k-1];
          matc[k,1]:=xar[i+k-1];
          matc[k,2]:=yar[i+k-1];
        end;

        deterc:=(matc[0,0]*matc[1,1]*matc[2,2])+(matc[0,1]*matc[1,2]*matc[2,0])+(matc[1,0]*matc[2,1]*matc[0,2])
    -(matc[2,0]*matc[1,1]*matc[0,2])-(matc[0,0]*matc[1,2]*matc[2,1])-(matc[1,0]*matc[0,1]*matc[2,2]);

        anow:=detera/deter;
        bnow:=deterb/deter;
        cnow:=deterc/deter;

    if i<15 then
      begin
      j:=0.025;
      xnow:=xar[i];
      while xnow<xar[i+1] do
        begin
          ynow:=a*xnow*xnow+b*xnow+cnow;
          Series1.AddXY(xnow,ynow, '', clBlack);
          xnow:=xar[i] + j;
          j:=j+0.025;
        end;
      end

      else
      begin
      j:=0.025;
      xnow:=xar[i-1];
      while xnow<xar[i+1] do
        begin
          xnow:=xar[i-1] + j;
          ynow:=a*xnow*xnow+b*xnow+cnow;
          Series1.AddXY(xnow,ynow, '', clBlack);
          j:=j+0.025;
        end;

      end;

    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем нашел я ошибку. В строке

```
  ynow:=a*xnow*xnow+b*xnow+cnow;
```

должно быть

```
ynow:=anow*xnow*xnow+bnow*xnow+cnow;
```

Вряд ли это кому-то интересно, но посчитал нужным отписаться.